# What is the name of the sound files for pressure plates in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm looking to stop sound on these files and have a silent pressure plate.
I already found `random.click`, but the pressure plate still makes a noise when walked over and activated.

Answer (score 1):

The names for the pressure plate sounds seem to be these:

```
block.wooden_pressure_plate.click_on
block.wooden_pressure_plate.click_off
block.stone_pressure_plate.click_on
block.stone_pressure_plate.click_off
block.metal_pressure_plate.click_on
block.metal_pressure_plate.click_off
```

You can find a full list of sounds [on this site.](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/sound_list_pc.php)